# Convert numbers in string to English word format

Tags: c#, regex

I have a C# method that converts integer numbers into their English word counterparts; however, how can I implement this so it'll work with a string.

For example, if I have the following string:

*There was a dog. The dog ate 1000 bones. After eating, he was very sleepy. He slept for 12 hours.*

I want it to parse it and return:

*There was a dog. The dog ate one thousand bones. After eating, he was very sleepy. He slept for twelve hours.*

How would I go by taking the numbers out of the sentence, and using the conversion method (below)?

```
public static string NumberToWords(int number)
{
    if (number == 0)
        return "zero";

    if (number < 0)
        return "minus " + NumberToWords(Math.Abs(number));

    string words = "";

    if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 1000000) + " million ";
        number %= 1000000;
    }

    if ((number / 1000) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 1000) + " thousand ";
        number %= 1000;
    }

    if ((number / 100) > 0)
    {
        words += NumberToWords(number / 100) + " hundred ";
        number %= 100;
    }

    if (number > 0)
    {
        if (words != "")
            words += "and ";

        var unitsMap = new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
        var tensMap = new[] { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

        if (number < 20)
            words += unitsMap[number];
        else
        {
            words += tensMap[number / 10];
            if ((number % 10) > 0)
                words += "-" + unitsMap[number % 10];
        }
    }

    return words;
}
```

I tried doing a foreach, like this, but it didn't work...

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(myString, "[0-9]+");
foreach(var match in matches)
{
   NumberToWords(match);
}
```

Comment: [This library](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer) will be useful for turning the numbers to words.

Comment: Is the statement in the `foreach` loop **exactly** as it appears in your program? If so, you are not keeping the data from your method longer than the iteration of the loop. Do something like user3451056's answer shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `Split` and `LINQ`:

```
var input = "There was a dog. The dog ate 1000 bones. After eating, he was very sleepy. He slept for 12 hours.";

var invalidChars = new [] { ',', ';', '-', '.' };
var words = input.Split(' ')
            .Select(x =>
            {
                if (x.All(char.IsDigit) || x.Trim(invalidChars).All(char.IsDigit))
                    return NumberToWords(int.Parse(x.Trim(invalidChars)));
                return x;
            });

var output = string.Join(" ", words);
```

Btw I assume that `NumberToWord` method is working correctly.

Comment: One monkey wrench: if the number is preceded or followed by a non-space (most likely punctuation or quotation marks) it won't be picked up. For example: "Jimmy turned 10." Not sure whether or not this is an issue for Zach.

Comment: Thanks! Now...is there a way to change it to `TryParse`, rather than just `Parse`? If I have, let's say `1200L` in the string, it'll throw an error "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: And in regards to @ChrisSinclair's comment, what is the best approach to avoid the issue if a number is preceded or followed by a non-space?

Comment: @Zach it won't throw actually.1200L doesn't count in this case because L is not a digit :) I will update my answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Selman22's approach, but in case you are not using a version of .NET with LINQ, you could use the RegularExpression replace function instead of Match.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx

You would just need a MatchEvaluator delegate like this:

```
static string matchEvaluator(Match m)
{
  return NumberToWords(int.Parse(m.ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Much more simple way is to use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy.aspx) method utilizing [MatchEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx).

```
string input = "There was a dog. The dog ate 1000 bones. After eating, he was very sleepy. He slept for 12 hours.";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+", m => NumberToWords(int.Parse(m.Value)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal Changes to your existing code:

```
string s = "There was a dog. The dog ate 1000 bones. After eating, he was very sleepy. He slept for 12 hours.";

foreach (var match in Regex.Matches(s, "[0-9]+"))
{
    string number = match.ToString();
    s = s.Replace(number, NumberToWords(int.Parse(number)));
}

Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: Try that with input `There were 10 dogs that ate 1000 bones.`  I get `There were ten dogs that ate ten00 bones.`  You seem to be expecting `Replace()` to replace only the only the one match that corresponds to the current `match` object, but it doesn't work that way.  In this case it's replacing all occurrences `10`, including the first two digits of `1000`.  Just use the `Regex.Replace()` method like [Ulugbek did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22585610/20938); that's what it's there for.